# Degree of map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ bounded by degree of divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a curve of genus $g$. Suppose $D$ is a divisor with $\dim H^0(D)\geq 2$. Then there exists a non-constant $f\in H^0(D)$. In the top answer to this question, [Hartshorne 4.1.6 Gonality of a curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720474/hartshorne-4-1-6-gonality-of-a-curve), it is stated that $f$ gives a finite morphism $f:X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree at most $\deg D$. My question is: Why is the degree of $f$ at most $\deg D$?

Answer (score 1):

If $|D|$ is base point free, $\deg(f) = \deg(D)$. Otherwise, if $P$ is a base point of $|D|$, the map given by $|D-P|$ is the same as the map $f$, therefore by induction $\deg(f) \le \deg(D-P) = \deg(D) - 1$.

Comment: Why does $|D|$ base point free imply that $\deg(f)=\deg(D)$?

Comment: Because by definition of $f$ the divisor $D$ is equal (as a scheme) to the fiber of $f$ over a point.

Comment: By definition, we have that $(f)+D\geq 0$, but I don't see how that implies what you wrote.

Comment: I am talking about the definition of the morphism given by a linear system.